# Looking for help to understand example of Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am looking for someone to help me to understand what is going on in the following example, from Hersteins "Topics in Algebra".

It says,

Let $G$ be the set of all $2*2$ matrices $$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \\ \end{pmatrix}$$ where $a,b,c,d$ are integers modulo $p$, $p$ is a prime number such that $ad-bc \neq 0$, with matrix multiplication having its usual definition, then verify that $G$ is a non-abelian finite group.

I think I am just even confused on some definitions. From what I understood previously, to say $a\equiv b \quad mod \quad n$ is to say that $n | a-b$.

So what is it to mean the these entries are integers modulo $p$? Can anyone share some insight about this? Thank you.

Comment: Equate two integers that are equivalent mod $n$. Call this set $\mathbb Z/n$. Then the standard addition and multiplication operations on $\mathbb Z$ define a ring structure on $\mathbb Z/n$ (i.e., it has addition and multiplication laws and they distribute). Herstein means the entries of his matrix live in the ring $\mathbb Z/n$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Integers_modulo_n) for more.

Comment: acctually since $p$ is prime your matrix entries are coimg from a finite field and your group is $GL (Z_p , 2)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, when one talks about the integers mod $p$, what one does is restrict oneself to the representatives of the equivalence classes that lie in: $\{0,1,2,\dots,p-1\}$.  One see the equivalence class of $a$ modulo $p$ denoted variously as: $\overline{a}$, $[a]_p$, or even (via a common abuse of notation) just $a$ itself (one has to then remember that $a$ (mod $p$) is *not* the same thing as the *integer* $a$).

Note that for *any* integer $a$, and any prime $p$, we can write:

$a = qp + r$ for a *unique* pair of integers $q,r$ with $0 \leq r < p$.

Since $a - r = qp$, ir follows that $a \equiv r$ (mod $p$). This justifies only considering the representatives of the equivalence classes  in my first paragraph, since these account for *all* of them.

So, for your purposes, it suffices to consider $a,b,c,d \in \{0,1,2,\dots,p-1\}$, writing $\overline{a},\overline{b},\overline{c},\overline{d}$ for the actual matrix entries (addition and multiplication are "different" for the integers modulo $p$, then in the "ordinary" integers- for example, $\overline{p-1} + \overline{1} = \overline{0}$, which certainly never happens for any positive prime *integer*).

The important thing to show, in this example, is that we have *closure*, to which end you might consider the properties of determinants (which still work in the integers modulo $p$, since these form a *field*-something you might not yet have covered at this point in Herstein).

Answer (score 1):

$G$ is group because if $x,y \in G$ then $x^{-1} y \in G$ and $G$ is nonabelian because:
$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \\ \end{pmatrix} *\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \\ \end{pmatrix} \neq \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 &  1\\ \end{pmatrix} *\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}$
And at last $G$ is finite because $|G|= (p^2-1)(p^2-p)$
**Remarks**: addition and multiplication in $G$ is like this:
For example if $p=7$ then $4*5 + 3^2=6+2=1$ ! because $4*5 \equiv 6 \mod {7}$ and $3^2=9 \equiv 2 \mod {7}$ and then $6+2=8 \equiv 1 \mod {7}$ hence:
$\begin{pmatrix} 4 & 3 \\ 0 & 1 \\ \end{pmatrix} *\begin{pmatrix} 5 & 1 \\ 3 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 \\ 3 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: $|G|=(p^2-1)(p^2-p)$ because we have $p^2-1$ choices for the fist row and $p^2-p$ choices for the second row by the linear independence condition for elements of $G$.

Comment: Your counter example doesn't work, because it also requires $ad-bc$ to be non-zero.

Comment: @vgmath: O! thanks, i edited this.

Answer (score 0):

The integers come from $0, 1, \dots, p-1$ and addition and multiplication are done $\mod{p}$.